# Python barcode library

Tags: python, python-2.7, barcode

I am looking for the python barcode library.
I am using ubuntu 12.04 and installed a [pyBarcode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyBarcode/) libarary to generate barcode. but it is not supporting.it give me error like,

```
>>> import barcode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named barcode
```

Any guess?

Comment: How did you install `pyBarcode`?

Comment: Downloaded the lib and then 
python setup.py install

Comment: Did that succeed? Was that run with the same `python` command you then tried the import with? What was the *output* of `python setup.py install`, could you add that to your question (you can [edit] it)?

Comment: `pyBarcode` hasn't been maintained in many years. `python-barcode` is a fork that includes a lot of various fixes from the community, so I'd stick to the latter.

Answer (score 1):

If you've not installed it in standard path/location, make sure your PYTHONPATH is pointing to directory where library is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check running `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` and then running adding `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` into the python file you're running.

Does the output of both differ? If so, then the PYTHONPATH (or maybe even `python` itself) in however you're running Python is different from the one `pip` used.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pdf 417` module. One of the easiest to use and the best